# Access VBA SQL Statement with LIKE & AND

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am trying to call an Access Query(QRY_TimecardStatus) from a form that has three fields: Weekending Date, Supplier Name, and Status Type (list box with multi-select).

Because the mult. select list box criteria needs to be created in VBA I found some code that works great!

```
 Set DB = CurrentDb()
 Set Q = DB.QueryDefs("QRY_TimecardStatus")
 Q.SQL = "Select * From Data Where [Approval Status] In(" & Criteria & ");"
```

However, I need to add the other two field criteria on to the code above. When manually inputting the SQL into the SQL view in Access, the additional two criteria SQL statements work like:

```
Like "*" & [Forms]![FRM_TimecardStatus]![suppliercb] & "*"
Like "*" & [Forms]![FRM_TimecardStatus]![StartDatetxt] & "*"
```

Can someone please help construct the VBA necessary to account for all three form fields and execute the query named (QRY_TimecardStatus)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you need to call an already defined Query if you try to build a new one - choose one or the other:

The following should work: it combines the three statments with `AND` (you could use `OR` too, not sure, what you need) and wraps it in `"`. You would need to specify the two fields you want to filter by though.

```
Set DB = CurrentDb()
Dim rs AS RecordSet
Set rs = DB.OpenRecordset "Select * From Data Where [Approval Status] In(" & Criteria & ") AND " & _
        "[OtherField] Like ""*" & [Forms]![FRM_TimecardStatus]![suppliercb] & "*"" AND " & _
        "[AnotherField] Like ""*" & [Forms]![FRM_TimecardStatus]![StartDatetxt] & "*"""
```